# How to hide the whole website?

Tags: html, css

How can I hide the whole content behind, for example, a black color or an image, but in a way that when the page loads I don't see any content, but just that color.

Comment: check out the MCVE please...http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: perhaps a more thought out question to explain what you are trying to do and what you have tried.. .these are the more relevant components missing from your question... less so is the "example"

Comment: Next time I will try to write about what I've already tried to do, but man I don't know how to ask this question in a more simple way. And thanks for the link, I'm sure I will read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the background-color of the html tag and hide the body tag.

```
html {
    background-color: blue;
}

body {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code at right after `<body>` tag:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

And declare following style for it:

```
.overlay{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: #000;
   z-index: 999;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: what happens if an element on the page is z-indexed higher?

Comment: You need to make sure that the z-index of `overlay` is the highest of all the elements.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this like below

apply css to body

```
body {
    display:none;
}
```

then add jQuery

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: where does it say the user wants to fade in the body? OP says "hide" the content" Nice effect, but not one that was asked for...